# Не работает hasClass, хотя класс задан

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть HTML:

```
<input type="button" id="a1" class="add">
<span id="price"></span>
```

и переменные `a1 = 350` и `sum = 0`.

При клике меняю класс:

```
$('#a1').click(function() {
    sum += a1;
    $('#price').html("Цена: " + sum);
    $('#a1').removeClass('add');
    $('#a1').addClass('del');
});
```

Потом проверяю наличие класса и при клике меняю его обратно на старый:

```
if ($("#a1").hasClass('del')) {
    $('#a1').click(function() {
        sum -= a1;
        $('#price').html("Цена: " + sum);
        $('#a1').removeClass('del');
        $('#a1').addClass('add');
    });
}
```

Но второй код (где я класс назад меняю) не работает. Почему?

Comment: потому что `$('#a1').click(function(){` **НЕ ВЫЗЫВАЕТ** обработчик, а только навешивает его

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Потому что, судя по коду, проверку на наличие класса `del` вы делаете сразу же, а не при клике на `#a1`. Соответственно, так как изначально класса `del` у элемента нет, то и **второй** обработчик события `click` к элементу не добавляется.

Имеет смысл добавить один обработчик события `click` на `#a1`, а внутри обработчика выполнять тот или иной код, основываясь на наличии класса у `#a1`:

```js
var sum = 0;
var a1 = 350;

$("#a1").on("click", function() {
    var sign = $(this).hasClass("add") ? 1 : -1;
    sum += sign * a1;
    $("#price").text("Цена: " + sum);
    $(this).toggleClass("add del");
});
```

```css
.add {
  background-color: green;
}
.del {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<span id="price">Цена: 0</span>
<input type="button" id="a1" class="add" />

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Спс, помогло! Чего сам не додумался...

Comment: А как добавить событие после проверки класса? Например кроме  span'a ещё и в **input** с id **inputPrice** кидать **sum**?

Comment: @ArtemPro "ещё и в input с id inputPrice кидать sum" - `$("#inputPrice").val(sum);`

Comment: спасибо, помогло!